# Touch ID with Firebase and Ionic 2? #askfirebase

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic2

Can you use Touch ID when you have Firebase as a backend and use Ionic 2?
This is my current code.

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
    touchid.checkSupport(() => {
        touchid.authenticate((result) => {
            ngZone.run(() => {
                this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
            });
        }, (error) => {
            alertCtrl.create({
                title: "Attention!",
                subTitle: error,
                buttons: ["Close"]
            });
        }, "Please Authenticate");
    }, (error) => {
        alertCtrl.create({
            title: "Attention!",
            subTitle: "Touch ID is not supported",
            buttons: ["Close"]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: The Touch Id function doesn't have nothing to do with backend. You can use with Ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to use Firebase with TouchID for something? Since your code is a authentication code sample. But if you want to yes, you can use it like when the authenticate result is true you can call a firebase method to do something.

They're not related, TouchID is a plugin and Firebase is a Database As A Service.

Comment: How are the 2 related? Meaning that if Touch ID result is authenticated, I need to translate the result with a user on Firebase.